# Swift 2.3 Crash if Facebook profile cannot be returned

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, forced-unwrapping

On my app the user has a profile picture, if signed in with Facebook the profile picture is set to there current Facebook profile picture. The issue i have is if the user signs into the app without Facebook the app crashes when trying to retrieve the Facebook data. How can i make it safe so if the Facebook data cannot be got then the profile picture can be set to blank.

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {


    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let photoUrl = user?.photoURL
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl!) 
        let profileView = UIImageView()
        profileView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        profileView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        profileView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        profileView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        profileView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
        profileView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        return profileView

}()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a NSData by force unwrapping an optional value, in this case `photoUrl`. I asumme that if the user did not log in with facebook, that value of that attribute is nil.

What you should do is instead of force unwrapping the `photoURL`, you should check if it is nil first. To do this, you can use a guard, which is the recommended way to check for something

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let photoUrl = user?.photoURL

    guard let photoUrl = user?.photoURL else {
        return UIImageView()
        //Here do the cusomization of the blank image before 
        //returning it
    }

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl) 
    let profileView = UIImageView()
    profileView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    profileView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

    profileView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    profileView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    profileView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
    profileView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    return profileView

}()
```

This way, you know that the photoURL will not be nil, otherwise, it will returning the blank image.